# Парсинг ответа vksdk

Tags: android

При помощи такой конструкции я парсю ответ ВК

```
r.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener(){
                public void onComplete(VKResponse r){
                    super.onComplete(r);
                    VKList<VKApiPost> posts = (VKList<VKApiPost>)r.parsedModel; 
                    for(int i=0;i<((VKList<VKApiPost>)r.parsedModel).size();i++){
}};
```

Но сейчас у меня уже есть string(ответ ВК) полученный другим способом и я хочу его распарсить  таким же способом.

```
VKList<VKApiPost> posts = (VKList<VKApiPost>)r.parsedModel;
```

Но здесь r типа VKResponse. А у меня string. Вопрос. Как можно создать этот VKResponse на основе string. Чтобы потом распарсить.

Comment: Ну... Покажите нам конструкторы этого VKResponse и свою строку.

Comment: Я не знаю какие конструкторы у VKResponse

Comment: А моя строка это обычний ответ от wall.search типа json

Comment: Декомпилируйте класс (Ctrl+ЛКМ на классе) или посмотрите исходники на GitHub-е.